# Cannot start gvim with photon-gui (can't find a valid font)

Tags: fonts, vim, qnx

I'm having a problem trying to get gvim 7.2 working under QNX6.4.1 and Photon. Every time I 
try to start it I get the following error:

E665: Cannot start GUI, no valid font found

and I get the console vim instead. I think I've problem with my Photon 
configuration, or gvim configuration. As I already wrote, I've been using Photon, no xorg or xfree. I suppose that all I need is to specify font path for gvim, but don't know how under Photon.

thx

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting an ancient thread here because I found a different solution that worked.

```
yum -y install ghostscript
```

which added some dependencies

```
(1/5): ghostscript-8.70-21.el6.x86_64.rpm                                              | 4.4 MB     00:00
(2/5): ghostscript-fonts-5.50-23.2.el6.noarch.rpm                                      | 590 kB     00:00
(3/5): libXfont-1.4.5-5.el6_7.x86_64.rpm                                               | 137 kB     00:00
(4/5): urw-fonts-2.4-10.el6.noarch.rpm                                                 | 3.1 MB     00:00
(5/5): xorg-x11-font-utils-7.2-11.el6.x86_64.rpm                                       |  75 kB     00:00
```

The critical ones were ghostscript-fonts and libXfont, which installed a few basic fonts and configured them for X11.

I'm putting this solution here because of the error message

```
E665: Cannot start GUI, no valid font found
```

which i also got when trying to invoke gvim in that same configuration over X.

Comment: The fonts were installed in /usr/share/fonts/.  So if that directory is empty, it's a good indicator that you need this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `.vimrc` file, this is explained in [vim tip 632](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_the_font_in_the_GUI):

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_photon")
    set guifont=Courier\ New:s11
  endif
endif
```